# Laravel Eloquent Won't Display Query

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have successfully displayed data from one table in one part of my application, but the data won't display in another part. I want to include the Record for the winning team of that year. My View returns nothing when it should return an integer. I am using laravel 5.6.

Controller

```
$seasonOneWins=gameData::where('homeTeam', '81-North Stars')
                      ->where('homeWin', '1')
                      ->where('year', '2016');
```

View:

```
@if($seasonOneWins)
   @foreach($seasonOneWins as $seasonOneWin)
     <p>{!!$seasonOneWin!!}<p>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

I can't get anything to display in between the foreach's. I assume this means that my formula is suggesting that there is nothing that meets those requirements when I know there is.

Comment: I have tried copying the exact eloquent equation from the other part of my code and it still displays nothing. Leading me to believe there is something wrong with my view?

Comment: Tryy adding get() method in your eloquent query? $seasonOneWins=gameData::where('homeTeam', '81-North Stars')- 
  >where('homeWin', '1')->where('year', '2016')->get();

Comment: As @Joseph mentions above you are missing one method in the query chain. You are missing the ->get() method at the end.

Comment: Ok, I figured out I idiotically had 81-North when it should just be 81 North, but I want to display the number of wins. So I want to display the number of "gets" or instances in the array. Any suggestions? Count doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, I am upvoting you but still a noob and can't cast it publicly

Comment: First, you've already figured out that the query you ran is missing `->get()` method. Make sure your query get what you want: try to print results by `dd( $seasonOneWins)` to see what structures Eloquent gives to you, then can easily debug your `foreach` statement.

Comment: @Bw70316 As per your comment:, you can use count() function to get the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a misunderstanding. I kept trying to use count() on a foreach, which caused an error. I had the wrong syntax in my view, instead of the foreach() I should have coded:

View

```
   <p>   {!!$seasonOneWins!!}<p>
```

Controller

```
   $seasonOneWins=GameData::where('team', '81 North Stars')
   ->where('win', '1')
   ->where('year', 2016)
   ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get()` method in your query to return a collection like this

```
$seasonOneWins = gameData::where('homeTeam', '81-North Stars')
    ->where('homeWin', '1')
    ->where('year', '2016')
    ->get();
```

After that you can loop to the collection return by your query.

Read the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-models).